# Posting file upload via AJAX returns empty dictionary on Flask side

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, forms, flask

I have a Flask app that was working until I added login functionality. The issue I'm having is I have a modal that the user can upload a file with.

HTML

```html
<p>Upload Photo</p>
          <form method="POST" name="upload_pic" id="upload_pic" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="exampleInputFile" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">
           Select file...
        </label>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="AddNotesSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Then an AJAX call to upload the file:

```js
// add notes post
  $('#AddNotesSubmit').on('click', function(e) {

      var notes = $("#note_text").val();
      var schedule_id = $("#noteSchID").text();

      console.log(notes);

      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/",
          data: { AddNotes: "", schedule_id: schedule_id, notes: notes },
          success:function(response){
             $('#response').text(JSON.stringify(response));
          }
      });

      var fullPath = $("#exampleInputFile").val();
      var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
      const form = $('#upload_pic')[0];
      const pic = new FormData(form);

      console.log(form);
      console.log(pic);
      console.log(filename);

      if (filename != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/upload_pic",
            data: pic,
            processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        });
      }


      $('#modalAddNotes').modal('hide');
  });

  });
```

And finally the Flask code I'm using to debug:

```py
@app.route('/upload_pic', methods=['POST'])
def upload_pic():
        print(' request.files: %s' %request.files)
        files = request.files.get('files[]')
        print(' files: %s' %files)
```

The command line output on the python side is:

```
request.files: ImmutableMultiDict([])
files: None
```

So it's returning an empty dictionary. Previously, when I used:

```py
uploaded_pic = request.files['exampleInputFile']
```

It worked, but now with that code included it throws a 400 error because the `'exampleInputFile'` is invalid key in the `request.files` dictionary. I removed the `@login_required` from the route and it didn't change anything.

Comment: `request.files.get('exampleInputFile')`

Comment: Where did you get `files[]` from? That's not the name of the file input.

Comment: In another thread it was mentioned 'files[]' should return a list of all files that were uploaded if it was a multi file upload... 'exampleInputFile' in the get('') returns the same error with an empty dictionary.

Comment: The argument has to match the `name="xxx"` attribute of the file input. That "other thread" presumably had `name="files[]"`

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I understand name = 'XXX' has to mactch the request.files['XXX'] however when I do that I get this error: 
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'exampleInputFile'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, it is difficult to see why your code is not working. In your example, the form tag is not closed. Also, you didn't describe how your javascript code is executed. Although I assume that you are using a click event, I tested your code with a submit event. I have come to the conclusion that the code works.

Here is the variant I used for testing:

```
  <p>Upload Photo</p>
    <form method="POST" name="upload_pic" id="upload_pic" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="exampleInputFile" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">
       Select file...
      </label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" id="AddNotesSubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form[name="upload_pic"]').submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          const form = event.target;
          const formData = new FormData(form);
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/upload_pic',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
          }).done((data) => {
            console.log(data);
          })
        });
      });
    </script>
```

```
@app.route('/upload_pic', methods=['POST'])
def upload_pic():
    if 'exampleInputFile' in request.files:
        file = request.files['exampleInputFile']
        if file.filename != '':
            # handle file here!
            return jsonify(success=True)
    return jsonify(success=False)
```

Comment: I added the full js code for the event. The top half handles the text part of the modal submission and it works correctly.

Comment: Thank you! You're code worked when I made a blank page with a new route for it. It's something else in the page that is messing with it.

Comment: @TonyD. I'm sorry, I can't find any errors in the code you wrote. I'm afraid I can't help you.